# i need help finding the min and max numbers of a dataset table in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, dataset

I need help finding the min and max numbers of a dataset table in shell script.

```sh
min=$(awk -F ',' -v min=999 'NR!=1 {if($'"$i"'<min){min=$'"$i"'}} END{print min}' $filename)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Look into GNU datamash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may use sort [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and sed ([for first and last](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139089/how-to-read-first-and-last-line-from-cat-output))

as in `sort -t , -k 2 the_file | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'`